# What are the particular cases `getchar()` returns error?

Tags: c, posix, stdio

So i know `getchar()` returns EOF when input ended or an error occurred. I also know that i can check which of this cases occurred by `ferror(stdin)` and `feof(stdin)`.
I want to know what are the cases when error can occur in particular.

I checked man pages of both functions but there is nothing about it there.

Comment: The man page for `fgetc` (which `getchars`'s ma page *explicitly* refers you to) lists *7* distinct errors; I wouldn't call that "nothing".

Comment: o_O Which man page? `what are the cases when error can occur in particular.` Well, you want to a list with errors like: "strucking your hard drive with a hammer mid operation"?

Comment: @ScottHunter: The `fgetc` man page on my system does not list seven distinct errors. The POSIX man page for `fgetc` does, but OP did not tag or state POSIX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getchar()` can return `EOF` for multiple system specific I/O errors. `getchar()` is defined to be equivalent to `getc(stdin)`, itself equivalent to `fgetc(stdin)` except for the fact that it may be implemented as a macro. Here is a list of possible causes for linux systems from the [linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3p.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, `fgetc()` shall return the next byte
> from the input stream pointed to by stream.  If the end-of-file
> indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-
> file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and
> `fgetc()` shall return `EOF`. If a read error occurs, the error
> indicator for the stream shall be set, `fgetc()` shall return `EOF`,
> and shall set `errno` to indicate the error.
>
> **ERRORS**
>
> The `fgetc()` function shall fail if data needs to be read and:
>
> `EAGAIN` The `O_NONBLOCK` flag is set for the file descriptor
> underlying stream and the thread would be delayed in the
> `fgetc()` operation.
>
> `EBADF`  The file descriptor underlying stream is not a valid file
> descriptor open for reading.
>
> `EINTR`  The read operation was terminated due to the receipt of a
> signal, and no data was transferred.
>
> `EIO`    A physical I/O error has occurred, or the process is in a
> background process group attempting to read from its
> controlling terminal, and either the calling thread is
> blocking `SIGTTIN` or the process is ignoring `SIGTTIN` or the
> process group of the process is orphaned.  This error may
> also be generated for implementation-defined reasons.
>
> `EOVERFLOW`
> The file is a regular file and an attempt was made to read
> at or beyond the offset maximum associated with the
> corresponding stream.
>
> The `fgetc()` function may fail if:
>
> `ENOMEM` Insufficient storage space is available.
>
> `ENXIO`  A request was made of a nonexistent device, or the request
> was outside the capabilities of the device.

Comment: I think we could benefit from simple examples or common-language translations of these. Like `EAGAIN`: The stream is set not to wait for data, but there is none available at the moment. `EBADF`: The stream is closed. `EIO`: Hardware malfunctioned. `EOVERFLOW`: The program read beyond the end of the file. `ENOMEM`: Memory was not available to create a buffer for the stream.

Answer (score 3):

All of stdio.h points at something called *error indicator*, which is an internal variable supposedly located in an opaque `FILE` object that the application programmer has no access to (see C17 7.21.1).

The documentation for `getchar` is found in C17 7.21.7.6:

> The getchar function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by
> stdin. If the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and
> getchar returns EOF. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and
> getchar returns EOF.

So we don't know if `getchar` returned `EOF` because it reached the end of the stream, or because there was a read error. In order to know, we'd have to check the error indicator.

This is where `ferror(stdin)` comes in. It's a mildly useful function, because it only does this (C17 7.21.10.3):

> The ferror function returns nonzero if and only if the error indicator is set for
> stream.

And that's all there is to it - this is a standardized, portable abstraction layer and we can't really know what's going on underneath the hood. Which is nice, because most of the time we simply don't care.

There will be an OS-specific API underneath these standard C functions, in case of POSIX likely `read()`, in case of Windows likely `ReadFile()` etc. These functions in turn can fail for a number of reasons: incorrect file handles, file is taken by another process, no read access to the file given to the user by the OS and so on.

In theory `getchar` could as well be hooked up to a serial bus on an embedded system, in which case the reasons of it failing would be entirely different ones than on a hosted system. Now we are suddenly talking about wrong baudrate, buffer overruns, framing errors or whatever applies.